# Inner Joins and retrieving the parent record if only its children record met certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Table CP

```
CP_Name  CP_Number  CP_PK
-------  ---------  -----
AA             111    123
BB             222    124
CC             333    125
DD             444    126
EE             555    127
FF             666    128
GG             777    129
```

Table PP

```
PP_Name  PP_Number  PP_Phase    PP_PK  Parent_PK
-------  ---------  ----------  -----  ---------
ABC          11111  Active        345        123
DEF          22222  Inactive      346        123
GHI          33333  Inactive      347        124
JKL          44444  Terminated    348        124
MNO          55555  TDR           349        126
PQR          66666  Active        350        126
STU          77777  Inactive      351        127
VWX          88888  Active        352        128
YX           99999  TDR           353        129
BCA          12121  Terminated    354        126
```

Results:

```
CP_Name  CP_Number  PP_Name  PP_Number  PP_Phase    CP_PK  Parent_PK
-------  ---------  -------  ---------  ----------  -----  ---------
AA             111  ABC          11111  Active        123        123
AA             111  DEF          22222  Inactive      123        123
DD             444  MNO          55555  TDR           126        126
DD             444  PQR          66666  Active        126        126
DD             444  BCA          12121  Terminated    126        126
```

I have two tables related by `CP_PK = Parent_PK`. Table `PP` is a child of Table `CP`.

I’m trying to find cases where Table `CP` has at least two children rows (could be more than two), where one of the child could be equal to `Inactive`, `Terminated` or `Transferred to TPD` and then the other child could be equal to `Active`, `TDR Approved`, `TDR Draft`, `TDR Final`. I started with an inner join of the two tables based off `CP_PK = Parent_PK` and then using `PP_Phase = 'xxx'` and a `Group By`, but quickly realized that wouldn’t work. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: This can be easily done by the use of conditional analytic functions. e.g. `count(distinct case when pp_phase in (...) then 1 end) over (partition by ...)`

Comment: Will this just return a count, or also other fields that we selected? Could you expand your example a little further out so I can try to write the full query please?

Comment: It tells you if there are any rows that meet your conditions. Then you can use that to filter your results by. I highly recommend you try this out for yourself, as you'll gain a better understanding.

Comment: I assume `Active` etc. refer to the `PP_Phase` column in Table `PP`. In the problem statement, you have the options `Transferred to TPD`, `TDR Approved`, `TDR Draft`, `TDR Final`. But in the sample data you don't have anything to do with `TPD` (which is OK, it illustrates what my happen in your data), and two instances of `TDR` but nothing like `TDR Approved` or `TDR Final` etc. Did you mean, in the sample data, to have these longer strings, not just `TDR`? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: It is also somewhat unclear what you need in the output. What seems clear is that you want rows from the join (rather than just single rows from table `PP`) for those rows from table `PP` for which the conditions are satisfied. But which rows need to be include in the output? ALL the rows for the `PP` row, or only those where the `PP_Phase` is in the lists you gave? Or just two rows, one with the `PP_Phase` in the first list and the other in the second list?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all my 'requirements' in the table data for the sake of time/effort in making the data. I'm basically looking for the following: All rows from the Table CP where all following are met 1. they have more than one child in Table PP 2. one of their child has to be of "Active", "TDR Approved", "TDR Draft" , and "TDR Final" phase 3. the other child has to be of "Inactive", "Terminated", or "Transferred to TDP" phase. There can be any combinations of them, but those three requirements should be met. There could be 2 to infinity number of child rows in Table PP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from (select Count(*) OVER (partition by CP.CP_PK) cnt, CP.* from CP              
                INNER JOIN PP  ON CP.CP_PK = PP.Parent_PK where some Condition1  or some condition2) a where a.cnt>1
```

Comment: When I use 'Some' it doesn't work, but I take it out and also the other condition then it works, but I'm missing my specific constraints then

Comment: no no no some is not key its only simple word)) remove it

Comment: also, can I select only certain fields from both tables for output instead of using * in the initial select statement? I tried, but got an invalid errors, so not sure if it is possible?

Comment: Yes , you can, its no problem

Comment: would you do 'Select cp.cp_pk, pp.parent_pk from (select Count....' as an example? I tried this out, but after I remove the *, the query didn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cp.*
FROM
  CP
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT parent_pk
    FROM   PP
    GROUP BY parent_pk
    HAVING COUNT(
             CASE WHEN Parent_PK IN ( 'Inactive', 'Terminated', 'Transferred to TPD'
                  THEN 1 END
           ) >= 1
    AND    COUNT(
             CASE WHEN Parent_PK IN ( 'Active', 'TDR Approved', 'TDR Draft', 'TDR Final'
                  THEN 1 END
           ) >= 1
  ) pp
  ON ( cp.cp_pk = pp.parent_pk )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what Boneist mentioned in his/her first Comment under your original post. Adapt as needed; this is not exactly what you need, but it should be sufficiently close and you should be able to modify it yourself.

```
with
     cp ( cp_name, cp_number, cp_pk ) as (
       select 'AA', 111, 123 from dual union all
       select 'BB', 222, 124 from dual union all
       select 'CC', 333, 125 from dual union all
       select 'DD', 444, 126 from dual union all
       select 'EE', 555, 127 from dual union all
       select 'FF', 666, 128 from dual union all
       select 'GG', 777, 129 from dual
     ),
     pp ( pp_name, pp_number, pp_phase, pp_pk, parent_pk ) as (
       select 'ABC', 11111, 'Active'    , 345, 123 from dual union all
       select 'DEF', 22222, 'Inactive'  , 346, 123 from dual union all
       select 'GHI', 33333, 'Inactive'  , 347, 124 from dual union all
       select 'JKL', 44444, 'Terminated', 348, 124 from dual union all
       select 'MNO', 55555, 'TDR'       , 349, 126 from dual union all
       select 'PQR', 66666, 'Active'    , 350, 126 from dual union all
       select 'STU', 77777, 'Inactive'  , 351, 127 from dual union all
       select 'VWX', 88888, 'Active'    , 352, 128 from dual union all
       select 'YX' , 99999, 'TDR'       , 353, 129 from dual union all
       select 'BCA', 12121, 'Terminated', 354, 126 from dual
     )
select cp_pk, cp_name, cp_number, pp_pk, pp_name, pp_number, pp_phase
from   ( select cp_pk, cp_name, cp_number, pp_pk, pp_name, pp_number, pp_phase,
                count(case when pp_phase in ('Active', 'TDR')          then 1 end) 
                                                     over (partition by cp_pk) as flag_1,
                count(case when pp_phase in ('Inactive', 'Terminated') then 1 end) 
                                                     over (partition by cp_pk) as flag_2
         from   cp join pp on cp.cp_pk = pp.parent_pk
       )
where  flag_1 > 0 and flag_2 > 0
;
```

**Output**:

```
CP_PK CP_NAME  CP_NUMBER PP_PK PP_NAME  PP_NUMBER PP_PHASE
----- ------- ---------- ----- ------- ---------- ----------
  123 AA             111   346 DEF          22222 Inactive
  123 AA             111   345 ABC          11111 Active
  126 DD             444   350 PQR          66666 Active
  126 DD             444   354 BCA          12121 Terminated
  126 DD             444   349 MNO          55555 TDR

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense now. So you have the inside query looking for plans in those phases (active,tdr.etc), giving it a flag when true, and then the other query looking for plans in the other phases (inactive, terminated,etc) giving it a flag when true and then gathering both results when both flags are greater than 0. I was able to get the inside query to work. but when I try to have the whole query where both flags are greater than 0, I'm getting an error 'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined'. Its not telling me where the error is and highlighting the line, but just overall. Ideas?

Comment: "Column ambiguously defined" means you have a column by the same name in both tables of a join, and you include the name without preceding it by the table name (or alias) somewhere in the query. In the example in your post that doesn't happen, because you prefixed each column name with the table name, as in `cp_number` and `pp_number`, so no confusion is possible. If in your real-life data the name is exactly the same, you'll have a problem; you will need to give each table an alias (such as `pp` and `cp`) and write column names as `pp.order_id` and `cp.order_id` and such.

Comment: "Inner query" refers to the entire nested SELECT statement (used in the FROM clause of the "outer" query). "Inner query" doesn't refer to the creation of the two flags. The two flags are both "created" in the SELECT clause of the subquery. They are both **conditional counts** (counts based on CASE expressions); that's what you seem to be calling "inner queries".

Comment: Got it, than you. So I'm not sure why, but when I do the larger select statement on the outside now I get 'ORA-00904: invalid identifier' when I know for sure its correct since all I did was copy it from the 'inside select' statement. My matched my query exactly to yours, but for some reason when I'm trying to set it where both flags have to be greater than 0, it won't run

Comment: Also, I was thinking about the last line where both flags are greater than 0. I think that wouldn't work because no row would have both flags? Wouldn't there need to be a clause where both flags have to be greater than 0 for the main CP?

Comment: The error message should tell you which identifier is invalid. Which is it? Then: to see how the flags work, use the sample data from this thread (instead of your actual data, which may be too much). To see how the flags look like, select just the inner query (which is enclosed in parentheses after the keyword FROM of the outer query) and run it by itself. You will see every row from the join, and you will see all the columns, including the two flags. Both flags are added to every row of the join. The best way to understand is to run it as I suggested and see for yourself.